# obtener el valor del select en el controlador con $request de un formulario laravel

Tags: laravel, select

Me gustaría saber como recuperar el valor del option elegido en mi select para usarlo en mi controlador. Se como recuperar el valor de un input pero no de un select.
Esta es mi vista donde creo el formulario.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('añadir2') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="form-group col-4 offset-md-4">
<label>Elige el tipo de producto a añadir</label>
<select id="ntabla" class="form-control">
<option value="bebidas">Bebidas</option>
<option value="comidas">Comidas</option>
<option value="postres">Postres</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Nombre</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" class="form-control">
<label>Stock</label>
<input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" value="" class="form-control">
<label>Precio</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">€</span>
</div>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="precio" id="precio" value="">
</div>
<label>URL</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" id="url" value="">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</form>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn btn-success" href="{{ url('inicio') }}">Volver</a>
</div>
```

Y en mi controlador tengo esta función a la que llamo y lo único que me falta es poder recuperar el valor del select, que no se como obtenerlo. No se si tengo que ponerle una id al select.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $request->validate([
        'nombre'=>'required',
        'precio'=>'required',
        'stock'=>'required'
    ]);

    if($request->get('select') == "bebidas"){
        $listado = new Bebida ([
        'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio' => $request->get('precio'),
        'stock' => $request->get('stock'),
        'url' => $request->get('url')
         ]);

    } elseif ($request->get('select') == "comidas" ) {
        $listado = new Comida ([
        'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio' => $request->get('precio'),
        'stock' => $request->get('stock'),
        'url' => $request->get('url')
         ]);

    }else {
        $listado = new Postre ([
        'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio' => $request->get('precio'),
        'stock' => $request->get('stock'),
        'url' => $request->get('url')
        ]);
    }
    $listado->save();
    return redirect('/inicios')->with('success', 'Se ha añadido correctamente');
}
```

Y ya se que repito algo de código, pero solo me falta eso :)

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código de la vista y el controlador, y también del código que has intentado para obtener dicho valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder recuperar el valor elegido de un `select` ebes hacerlo a través del atributo `name` de esa misma etiqueta.

Entonces primero a esa etiqueta debes colocarle un nombre, así:

```
<select id="ntabla" name="tipo" class="form-control">
```

Entonces en el controlador recuperar dicha elección así:

```
if($request->get('tipo') == "bebidas"){
```

Comment: vale si funcionaba lo que pasa que tenia un fallo en el codigo, gracias ^^